# How to change the css with Directive?

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to add a color for a date if it's expired.

this is my code with Directive:

```
<td appDateExpired [checkExpired]="expt.expectedDate" class="p-2">{{expt.expectedDate | date :'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

I generated a Directive which colors my date with red , I tried to add so it would be colored only if the date is expired

any suggestions how to do it ?

this is my Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDateExpired]'
})
export class DateExpiredDirective {

@Input() checkExpired

  constructor(el: ElementRef) { 

    if(JSON.stringify(this.checkExpired) < JSON.stringify(new Date) ){
  el.nativeElement.style.color = "red";
}

}
```

Comment: What is `appDateExpired` ?

Comment: Can you show your directive `appDateExpired`. I believe we can change the same directive for color change as well.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I edited my question and now it's written there

Comment: What do you check if the date is expired? You said you tried to do `if` but you haven't posted it here so we can see...

Comment: you can color the date using the `ngClass` if the date is expired

Comment: @Dino I edited it again with all the missing details

Comment: @ram12393 looking for it on google ,thanks

Comment: let me know if you need any help in `ngClass`

Comment: @ram12393 would be nice of you can help a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[ngClass]` in order to change the class of the element depending on some condition or conditions.

```
<div [ngClass]="{ expiredDate: expectedDate < someDate }">
  {{ expectedDate }}
</div>
```

You can see that I am checking if `expectedDate` is less than `someDate`. If that condition is satisfied the `expiredDate` class will be applied to that element.

```
.expiredDate {
  color: red;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkwy2a)

Comment: you can use directly `[style.color]="expected<someDate?'red':'inherit'"`

Comment: True, how ever you cannot do more than one check then

Comment: well, my comment it's only about use [style.color] vs use [ngClass]. I supouse the comment was more clearer if I was wrote `[style.color]="expt.expectedDate<someDate?'red':'inherit'"`